# Do I have to know $f$ is injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given: 
$h: A \to A$
$g: A \to A$
If $f\circ h = f \circ g$ and $f$ is injective and I want to prove that $g = h$, why do I need to know that $f$ is injective? It doesn't matter right?

Comment: Suppose that $f$ sends any element in $A$ to $a\in A$. Then $f(g(b)) = a = f(h(b))$ for all $b\in A$, even if $g\neq h$.

Comment: You certainly do need that. Otherwise, take for example $f$ to send everything to the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does matter.

If $f$ is not injective, then (by definition) there is $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. And then it might be that for some $a$ we have $h(a)=x$ and $g(a)=y$ which would make $h$ and $g$ different even though this difference cannot be seen on $f\circ g$ and $f\circ h$.